# Global Popover Function in Swift 1.2 on iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have this function that I use all over my app, and it would be nice to create a global function:

```
class CustomReportVC: UIViewController, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

  func showPicker(pickerValues:[String], field:UITextField) -> AnyPickerVC{
    //Set up modal
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Popovers", bundle: nil)
    let modal = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AnyPickerModal") as! AnyPickerVC
    modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    let pc = modal.popoverPresentationController
    pc?.permittedArrowDirections = .Down
    pc?.sourceView = field
    pc?.sourceRect = field.bounds
    modal.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300,180)
    pc?.delegate = self

    //Pass in data
    modal.data = pickerValues

    //Set the value from within the picker controller
    modal.passDataToParent = { (value) in
      field.text = value
    }

    return modal
  }

  //Required for the popover
  func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .None
  }

}
```

The issue I'm running into comes with `pc?.delegate = self`. Since `CustomReportVC` conforms to `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`, this works fine.

But once I attempt to create this as a global function outside a class that conforms to this protocol, I get an error:

```
func globalShowPicker(pickerValues:[String], field:UITextField, controller:UIViewController) -> AnyPickerVC{
  //...
  pc?.delegate = controller //<-- ( ! ) Type UIViewController does not conform to UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate  
}
```

Whether I make `controller` a `UIViewController` or `AnyObject`, it doesn't conform. Is there a way to pass in the protocol conformity to the global function somehow?

Any idea how I can pull this off? Thanks. :)

Comment: Couldn't you just make the type of the `controller` argument be `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` so your function signature would be `func globalShowPicker(pickerValues:[String], field:UITextField, controller:UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate) -> AnyPickerVC`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your global function generic to specify that it only works for *certain* kinds of UIViewControllers. In this example, `T` can take the value of any UIViewController type which also conforms to the other protocols listed.

```
func globalShowPicker< T: UIViewController where
    T: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate,
    T: UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate > 
    (pickerValues:[String], field:UITextField, controller: T) -> AnyPickerVC
{
   //...
   pc?.delegate = controller 

   return blah
}
```

It does get kinda long, and I haven't figured out the best way to indent all the constraints. But it works.

Comment: Hmm... I still get the same error after listing the protocols like this.

Comment: Oops, I originally had the `controller` parameter still typed as `UIViewController` instead of `T`. Does it work as shown now?

Comment: Yep, it works great. This is a very slick answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a making a new class that inherits from both of them. Like this.

```
class PopoverController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

}
```

Then, switch the function to look like this.

```
func globalShowPicker(pickerValues:[String], field:UITextField, controller: PopoverController) -> AnyPickerVC{
  //...
  pc?.delegate = controller  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
self.presentViewController(pc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Btw, if you're doing Universal you can not present iPad UIActivityViewController like iPhone. You need to present it in a popover as per the design guidelines suggested by Apple.

or as an example

```
@IBAction func shareButtonClicked(sender: UIButton)
{
let textToShare = "Text"

if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/")
{
    let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:  objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    var nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: activityVC)
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    var popover = nav.popoverPresentationController as UIPopoverPresentationController!
    activityVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(500,600)
    popover.sourceView = self.view
    popover.sourceRect = CGRectMake(100,100,0,0)

    self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
}


class MyViewController : UIViewController,   UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
//code here
}
```

Comment: Yes, this comes after my global function... I'm just trying to prep the view to present first.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the delegate as a parameter in the function like this:

```
class CustomReportVC: UIViewController, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    class func showPicker(pickerValues:[String], field:UITextField, delegate: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate) -> UIViewController {
        //Set up modal
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Popovers", bundle: nil)
        let modal = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AnyPickerModal") as! UIViewController
        modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        let pc = modal.popoverPresentationController
        pc?.permittedArrowDirections = .Down
        pc?.sourceView = field
        pc?.sourceRect = field.bounds
        modal.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300,180)
        pc?.delegate = delegate

        //Pass in data
        modal.data = pickerValues

        //Set the value from within the picker controller
        modal.passDataToParent = { (value) in
            field.text = value
        }

        return modal
    }

    //Required for the popover
    func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .None
    }

}
```

You have at the end to have an instance of a view controller that does conform to the protocol, but that way you will have the function global just like you want and pass self pointer in the view controller that does conform to the protocol "UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate":

```
CustomReportVC.showPicker(pickerValues:....., delegate: self)
```